# Issue in Updating the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to UPDATE  a table from a CSV values that i am fetching from another table. This CSV value is output of a subquery that i created on the basis of variable in #Form table. Now i want to update the #Form table again  and i dont want to use cursor.
I am unable to update the #Form table correctly.

Below is the code i am using.

```
Update f
SET AuditorComment = (
    Select @Comment = @Comment+', '+a.Value
    FROM #Form fd
    LEFT JOIN AuditData a on (fd.FormID=a.objectID and a.ObjectTypeID=12 )
    WHERE  FORM_OID=@frmOID AND SubjectID=@subjectId AND f.FormID = fd.FormID 
    )
From #Form f
```

Kindly help me where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Explain the problem.

Comment: @Blorgbeard i have update dthe question. Thanks for commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to work like that.  You need to use the `for xml path` or a similar method:

```
update f
    set AuditorComment = stuff((select ', ' + ad.value
                                from formdata fd join
                                     AuditData ad 
                                     on fd.FormID = ad.objectID and ad.ObjectTypeID = 12
                                where FORM_OID = @frmOID and
                                      SubjectID = @subjectId and
                                      f.FormID = fd.FormID 
                                for xml path ('')
                               ), 1, 2, '')
    From #Form f;
```

Comment: The Select is giving multiple rows and because of which i am getting an error. Subquery returned more than 1 value. Using CSV i was trying to convert mulktiple rows into CSV record

Comment: You missed adding FOR XML PATH ('') after f.FormID = fd.FormID. It worked after adding this. Thanks..!!

Comment: @NimbleFungus . . . You also want `1, 2, '')` as the last three arguments to `stuff()` -- so you get rid of both the comma and the period.